# How can I receive notifications about ticket sales by various airlines?

Tags: air-travel, price

I will be travelling in December so have plenty of time to book tickets and want to wait for discount schemes.

I missed out on discount scheme of wowair just few weeks back. So wanted to check if it is possible to setup discount alerts for various airlines?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6370/is-there-a-site-where-i-can-subscribe-for-cheap-flight-for-a-specific-place

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Google Flights](https://www.google.com/flights) for this. If you search for a certain route and dates, you can then activate alerting and monitoring for prices on that route (on the result page there is a checkbox called “Track prices”). However I’m not sure if this only appears if you’re logged in with a Google account.

Comment: Unfortunately I see no way to get notification about new attractive prices, only about how price change for specific route on specific dates.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up 'fare alerts' in popular apps/websites such as Momondo. Skyscanner and Google Flights. These may or may not capture discounts or flash sales. The other alternative is to subscribe to individual airlines newsletters, which may make you aware whenever a discount or flash sale is offered

Comment: "which is sure to make you aware whenever a discount or flash sale is offered" it's definitely not sure. Airlines are often tweaking their prices outside of formal sales. And not every sale is publicized. But I'll give you a +1 for the rest of the answer

Comment: @Calchas THAT is precisely my point. Those subscriptions also act as a bait. Speaking from experience, once you are on their newsletter, they'll send you "sale" related emails every now and then. Many a naive customer will "fall" for this gimmick and most purchase from these sales, without bothering to compare prices.

Comment: And I totally agree to your point about tweaking prices outside of formal sales. Qatar Airways is my latest addition to this list. Till last year, it used to have genuine sales. However since the last ~6 months I've been noticing their prices are inflated vis-a-vis their normal fares.

Comment: Is there any way to get notification about broader date range? I looked at Skyscanner, Google Flights and Momondo - I see only way to get notifications about flight on a specific dates (what is not really useful - only when one wants to fly only if price drops from current one and is unwilling to change flight dates)