# Is there a platform that would let me automatically buy a plane ticket given a certain set of conditions?

Tags: bookings, flight-search-engines

Let's say I want to fly from Prague to New York, with 1 stop or direct, on a route that takes less than 16 hours. I don't particularly care about the airline, the exact times, the exact airports in New York, etc. The only thing I care about is the price and I want to *automatically* purchase a ticket if it's less than $300 on a given day. Currently the lowest price I can see is $380, but perhaps a great deal will pop-up in the future.

Is there a platform or at least an API that would allow me to do so? There is a [related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6370/is-there-a-site-where-i-can-subscribe-for-cheap-flight-for-a-specific-place) about being *notified* if such a cheap flight pops up, but in my case I want everything done automatically and the only notification I need is an actual ticket in my inbox whenever it's booked.

Comment: Agreed this is a very smart idea, especially considering many airlines allow cancellation for 24 hours after purchase. I've learned to grab a hugely discounted ticket as soon as I see them, especially when searching late at night - I'm guessing airlines sometimes push crazy cheap prices through for a short period of time to "trick" sites that cache prices so they appear cheapest. Would be smart to build something to grab these.

Comment: I see complication with this.  Will you accept any ticket?  What if there are baggage fees for checked bags, or even for carry-on bags?  What if you must buy all meals on board?  Are you prepared to buy a ticket if there is a seat reservation fee?  If you were completely un-fussy about what you booked, I could see this being possible, but the more of these variables you add, the more difficult it gets to make it work.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie presumably I would enter my luggage requirements at the start (carry on only vs. 1 checked in bag would be sufficient). Meals on board is irrelevant. Seat reservation fees are usually not mandatory as long as you're okay with a random seat.

Comment: You could easily end up buying two tickets; unless you are thinking of some kind of lockout on future purchases.

Comment: @Nick obviously only one ticket would be purchased for one set of conditions and one set of dates. Ideally I would have an API to code this myself but it seems impossible right now.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for an electronic way to do this? I would think a Travel Agent might be able to do this for you, would contacting one be a route?

Comment: @BruceWayne probably not as I want to setup multiple routes to monitor and cancel/change them at a moments notice. Dealing with a human is likely to be too expensive and too slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of any service, however, here are some points in case you want to build this yourself - which is possible if perhaps impractical unless you can scale it out.

Even if an aggregator (like skyscanner) were to give you an API to their service, they can't actually book a ticket for you - this requires access to the GDS and a license - since booking on these systems are made on credit.

So to do this yourself you would need to get an API to the GDS, and a travel agent license.

Next, simply write a script to query the GDS every *x* seconds (there is no notification system in GDS, you have to query for results) for your criteria - and on the first availability it will book your ticket.

You will have to then, at the end of the billing cycle, settle your account with the GDS for bookings done.

Answer (score 1):

I think your are talking about C2B model.
Priceline once offered this kind of service - "Name-Your-Own-Price" (NYOP). But Priceline stopped NYOP service for flight.

Comment: I don't mind this as an answer.  Essentially, "Once upon a time you could, but no longer."

Answer (score 1):

Hopper had auto-buy but it quietly disappeared.  I purchased using the autobuy name your price on tickets to Orlando and loved it but they must have run into issues.